# How to generate logs or print something during model fit in python3

Tags: python-3.x, logging, hierarchical-clustering

I am scheduling my `Jupyter Lab notebook` which has `cluster algorithm.`. The job fails if I do not `print` or `log` something. ( This is how it is designed).

Code:

```
import hdbscan
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

data, _ = make_blobs(1000000)

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=100)
cluster_model = clusterer.fit(data)
```

The line `clusterer.fit(data)` takes around `7-8` hrs for big data-set.

**How can I print or log something at the time of fitting so that Kernel doesn't become ideal?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but if you mean that the job gets killed by some "supervisor" if it doesn't print anything for too long, you could just start a separate [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) or [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) that does nothing but print stuff until the fit is complete:

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def print_target():
  while True:
    print("fit still running...")
    sleep(60)

# your code before fit...

proc = Process(target=print_target)
proc.start()

cluster_model = clusterer.fit(data)
proc.kill()
```

The example uses a `Process` instead of a `Thread` because the former are easier to kill (`Thread` doesn't have a `kill()` method like `Process` has, so you'd have to use a `threading.Queue` or `threading.Event` to communicate to the thread that you want it to stop running).